# python requests: post and big content

Tags: python, python-requests

I am sending a CSV file to a server using a POST request.

I am using a file-like object with `requests.post`

Will there be a problem if the CSV file is quite big and I have limited memory or the fact that I use a file-like object will never load the whole file in memory? I am not sure about that.

I know there is the stream option but it sounds like it's more for getting the response and not sending data.

```
headers = {
    'content-type': 'text/csv',
}
csvfile = '/path/file.csv'
with open(csvfile) as f:
    r = requests.post(url, data=f, headers=headers)
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Using an open file object as the `data` parameter ensures that `requests` will stream the data for you.

If a file size can be determined (via the OS filesystem), the file object is streamed using a 8kb buffer. If no filesize can be determined, a `Transfer-Encoding: chunked` request is sent sending the data *per line* instead (the object is used as an iterable).

If you were to use the `files=` parameter for a multipart POST, on the other hand, the file would be loaded into memory before sending. Use the [requests-toolbelt package](http://toolbelt.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) to stream multi-part uploads:

```
import requests
from requests_toolbelt.multipart.encoder import MultipartEncoder

csvfile = '/path/file.csv'
with open(csvfile) as f:
    m = MultipartEncoder(fields={'csv_field_name': ('file.csv', f, 'text/csv')})
    headers = {'Content-Type': m.content_type}
    r = requests.post(url, data=m, headers=headers)
```

Comment: in what module is ``open_file_handle``?

Comment: @YAmikep: There isn't; it is a symbolic name I made up to illustrate that this applies to open filehandles.  Your `f` is such a  filehandle.

Comment: oh ok so the way I am doing it already avoids loading the entire file into memory. Thanks.

Comment: Is it possible to configure the buffer to be larger than 8kb when sending a single file this way? seems like it limits the maximum throughput.

Comment: @jgstew the buffer size is set by urllib3; you would have to create a [custom HTTP adapter](https://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/advanced/#transport-adapters) that gives the pool manager a different buffer size.

Comment: @jgstew I’d override [`HTTPAdapter.init_poolmanager()`](https://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/api/#requests.adapters.HTTPAdapter.init_poolmanager) to add `blocksize=…` to the keyword arguments.

Comment: Seems like the `blocksize` is actually within `urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection`

Comment: @jgstew: yes, but the pool manager passes on the `blocksize` argument when it creates connections.

Comment: Interesting. Is that handled within `**pool_kwargs` because I don't see `blocksize` anywhere as I am going down the rabbit hole of the named arguments, but I assume if I go deep enough it will show itself.

Comment: @jgstew: yes, that's handled by `**pool_kwargs`, passed on to the pool object, which in turn passes on arguments it doesn't directly name to the connection.

Comment: @jgstew: see the [Pool Manager docs](https://urllib3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/urllib3.poolmanager.html) (*Additional parameters are used to create fresh `urllib3.connectionpool.ConnectionPool` instances*) and the [Connection Pool docs](https://urllib3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/urllib3.connectionpool.html#urllib3.HTTPConnectionPool) (*Additional parameters are used to create fresh `urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection`, `urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection` instances*)

Comment: @MartijnPieters I just tried overriding `HTTPAdapter.init_poolmanager()` as you suggested, and I did figure it out, but overriding blocksize is not possible with the newest release of urllib3 but it is in the main branch yet to be released. See here: https://github.com/urllib3/urllib3/blob/1.26.8/src/urllib3/poolmanager.py#L39-L68

Comment: @jgstew Ah, such is the issue with projects publishing their master branch as the 'latest' documentation. :-(

Answer (score 3):

This will not load the entire file into memory, it will be split into chunks and transmitted a little at a time. You can see this in the source code [here](https://github.com/kennethreitz/requests/blob/master/requests/models.py#L419).

Comment: Link goes to the wrong line now. Should be re-created with a specific commit instead of pointing to master branch.