# OverflowError: string longer than 2147483647 bytes

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

soo modification i made in streamtape-api github soo when i run it it gives me error

> ```
> import requests
> import hashlib
> import glob
> import os.path
>
>
> # Upload
> def upload(login, key, file_path):
>     sha256_hash = hashlib.sha256()
>     with open(file_path, "rb") as f:
>         for byte_block in iter(lambda: f.read(4096), b""):
>             sha256_hash.update(byte_block)
>         sha256 = sha256_hash.hexdigest()
>     url = f'https://api.streamtape.com/file/ul?login={login}&key={key}&sha256={sha256}'
>     data = requests.get(url).json()
>     upload_url = data['result']['url']
>     file = {'file': open(file_path, 'rb')}
>     upload_request = requests.post(upload_url, files=file)
>     upload_response = upload_request.json()
>     return upload_response
>
> #--------------------------------------------->Beast Modification<---------------------------------------------#
> fforfl = input("Do you want to upload full folder or file list (ff/fl) : ")
> login="LOGIN"
> key="KEY"
>
> if fforfl == "ff":
>     file_path=input("Please Enter Folder Path: ")
>     files = glob.glob(os.path.join(file_path, '*.mp4'))
>     videos = 0
>     for i in files:
>         videoname = files[videos]
>         result = upload(login, key, videoname)
>         videos +=1
>         print("Uploaded: " + videoname)
> elif fforfl == "fl":
>     videos = 0
>     file_path=input("Please Enter File List TXT Path: ")
>     files = [line.rstrip('\n') for line in open(file_path, 'r')]
>     for i in files:
>         videoname = files[videos]
>         result = upload(login, key, videoname)
>         videos +=1
>         print("Uploaded: " + videoname)
>
> else:
>     console.print("You have entered wrong input;\nGoodBye",style="italic red")
> ```

Error Message

> Do you want to upload full folder or file list (ff/fl) : fl
> Please Enter File List TXT Path: /content/Streamtape/filelist.txt
> tcmalloc: large alloc 2532188160 bytes == 0x55e3a618a000 @  0x7f7cf0ff31e7 0x55e3a4778338 0x55e3a4742ad7 0x55e3a48c1575 0x55e3a485b8b8 0x55e3a47463a2 0x55e3a4824c6e 0x55e3a4745ff9 0x55e3a4837d4d 0x55e3a47b9ec8 0x55e3a47477aa 0x55e3a47b9d30 0x55e3a47b4a2e 0x55e3a474788a 0x55e3a47b5b4f 0x55e3a47b4a2e 0x55e3a474788a 0x55e3a47b6719 0x55e3a47477aa 0x55e3a47b5b4f 0x55e3a47b4a2e 0x55e3a474813c 0x55e3a4748341 0x55e3a47b6ff1 0x55e3a47b4a2e 0x55e3a4686e2b 0x55e3a47b6ff1 0x55e3a47b4a2e 0x55e3a474788a 0x55e3a47b6719 0x55e3a47b4cdd
> tcmalloc: large alloc 2532188160 bytes == 0x55e43d06c000 @  0x7f7cf0ff31e7 0x55e3a4779407 0x55e3a474317c 0x55e3a482347a 0x55e3a4745f9d 0x55e3a4837d4d 0x55e3a47b9ec8 0x55e3a47b4a2e 0x55e3a474788a 0x55e3a47b58f6 0x55e3a47477aa 0x55e3a47b9d30 0x55e3a47b4a2e 0x55e3a474788a 0x55e3a47b5b4f 0x55e3a47b4a2e 0x55e3a474788a 0x55e3a47b6719 0x55e3a47477aa 0x55e3a47b5b4f 0x55e3a47b4a2e 0x55e3a474813c 0x55e3a4748341 0x55e3a47b6ff1 0x55e3a47b4a2e 0x55e3a4686e2b 0x55e3a47b6ff1 0x55e3a47b4a2e 0x55e3a474788a 0x55e3a47b6719 0x55e3a47b4cdd
> tcmalloc: large alloc 3165241344 bytes == 0x55e4d3f4e000 @  0x7f7cf0ff4615 0x55e3a474317c 0x55e3a482347a 0x55e3a4745f9d 0x55e3a4837d4d 0x55e3a47b9ec8 0x55e3a47b4a2e 0x55e3a474788a 0x55e3a47b58f6 0x55e3a47477aa 0x55e3a47b9d30 0x55e3a47b4a2e 0x55e3a474788a 0x55e3a47b5b4f 0x55e3a47b4a2e 0x55e3a474788a 0x55e3a47b6719 0x55e3a47477aa 0x55e3a47b5b4f 0x55e3a47b4a2e 0x55e3a474813c 0x55e3a4748341 0x55e3a47b6ff1 0x55e3a47b4a2e 0x55e3a4686e2b 0x55e3a47b6ff1 0x55e3a47b4a2e 0x55e3a474788a 0x55e3a47b6719 0x55e3a47b4cdd 0x55e3a474788a
> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "/content/Streamtape/streamtape-api.py", line 67, in 
> result = upload(login, key, videoname)
> File "/content/Streamtape/streamtape-api.py", line 43, in upload
> upload_request = requests.post(upload_url, files=file)
> File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/requests/api.py", line 119, in post
> return request('post', url, data=data, json=json, **kwargs)
> File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/requests/api.py", line 61, in request
> return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
> File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 530, in request
> resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
> File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 643, in send
> r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
> File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 449, in send
> timeout=timeout
> File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 600, in urlopen
> chunked=chunked)
> File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 354, in _make_request
> conn.request(method, url, **httplib_request_kw)
> File "/usr/lib/python3.7/http/client.py", line 1281, in request
> self._send_request(method, url, body, headers, encode_chunked)
> File "/usr/lib/python3.7/http/client.py", line 1327, in _send_request
> self.endheaders(body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
> File "/usr/lib/python3.7/http/client.py", line 1276, in endheaders
> self._send_output(message_body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
> File "/usr/lib/python3.7/http/client.py", line 1075, in _send_output
> self.send(chunk)
> File "/usr/lib/python3.7/http/client.py", line 997, in send
> self.sock.sendall(data)
> File "/usr/lib/python3.7/ssl.py", line 1034, in sendall
> v = self.send(byte_view[count:])
> File "/usr/lib/python3.7/ssl.py", line 1003, in send
> return self._sslobj.write(data)
> OverflowError: string longer than 2147483647 bytes

i want to upload video of 4gb to streamtape. but it gives me this error OverflowError: string longer than 2147483647 bytes

Comment: Please take a look at the stack trace: it will tell you the exact line where the error ocurrs; this may point in the right direction

Comment: ok soo here is the error message bro and thanks for replying

Comment: Take a look at this part of the message: `/content/Streamtape/filelist.txt tcmalloc: large alloc 2532188160`; it seems to be blowing up when loading the file list. How big is `filelist.txt`?

Comment: 2147483647 bytes so happens to be *exactly* 2 GiB. Is there an upload limit for the site or the API?

Comment: 3kb and the file path is something like this
/content/drives/HHPB01/Z.XXXX/XXX Collection/XXXXXX XXXXXX/XXXXXX XXXXXX - WTAWDF aWADd.mp4

Comment: no upload limit is 15gb per file check streamtape.com and the file size is 2.1gb something

Comment: Looking further into the stack trace, there's this line: `"/content/Streamtape/streamtape-api.py", line 43, in upload upload_request = requests.post(upload_url, files=file)`; meybe `requests.post()` is somehow trying to build the entire request into memory instead of streaming it?

Comment: Please, take a look at this answer to another post: https://stackoverflow.com/a/22915488/679240

Comment: come on bro help me out..sooo dev used same code here 
    url = f'https://api.streamtape.com/file/ul?login={login}&key={key}&sha256={sha256}'
    data = requests.get(url).json()
    upload_url = data['result']['url']
    file = {'file': open(file_path, 'rb')}
    upload_request = requests.post(upload_url, files=file)
    upload_response = upload_request.json()
    return upload_response